# Error 1064 en función con SELECT...INTO

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta función que me da el siguiente código de error y no sé qué puede estar mal. El delimiter no es porque en mi editor no hace falta ponerlo.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(*) INTO veces
> FROM authentication_tokens INNER JOIN users
> ON auth' at line 8

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_maxloginpassbolt() RETURNS VARCHAR(100) DETERMINISTIC BEGIN

DECLARE usuario VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE veces numeric;
DECLARE frase varchar(100);

SELECT users.username INTO usuario, COUNT(*) INTO veces 
FROM authentication_tokens INNER JOIN users
ON authentication_tokens.user_id=users.id
WHERE type='login' AND authentication_tokens.created BETWEEN 
CONCAT (YEAR(CURDATE()),'01-01') AND 
CONCAT (YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(CURDATE()),'-',DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()),
          ' ',HOUR(NOW()),':',MINUTE(NOW()),':',SECOND(NOW()))
GROUP BY authentication_tokens.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1;  

SET frase=CONCAT ('EL usuario que más ha usado Passbolt desde el 1 de enero hasta
el dia de hoy durante el año ',YEAR(CUDATE()),'ha sido ',usuario,' con ',
veces,' inicios de sesion');

RETURN frase;  END
```

Un `describe` de las tablas me da esto:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE authentication_tokens;
```

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | char(36)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| token    | char(36)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| user_id  | char(36)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| active   | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| created  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modified | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| type     | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| data     | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0,02 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE users;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | char(36)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| role_id  | char(36)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| username | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| active   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| deleted  | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| created  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modified | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta un guion entre el año y el mes de la primera fecha del `BETWEEN`. Por favor, cópianos en la pregunta el `DESCRIBE` de las tabla en modo texto.

Comment: Ya esta. Añadi ese guion pero no va

Comment: te acabo de poner la solución @Adrián

Comment: Avisame @Adrián si te ha funcionado

Comment: `SELECT users.username INTO usuario, COUNT(*) INTO veces `: ¿es correcto? Revisando la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html), la sintaxis pareciera ser algo así como `SELECT users.username, COUNT(*) INTO usuario, veces`.

Comment: @padaleiana yo siempre lo colocó así me pareció raro eso pero pensé que era otra forma de hacerlo 

Comment: @JavierG.Raya lo pregunto desde mi completa ignorancia, tal vez en MySQL es distinto (mi suposición se basa en la sintaxis en Oracle, por eso me remití a la documentación de MySQL)

Comment: @padaleiana yo he usado esa estructura de mysql como pusiste ahora si hay otra manera de usar el select into pues eso ya no se

Comment: @Adrián si te ha funcionado no te olvide de votarla positivamente

Comment: Mas o menos. El problema es que ahora no da error de sintaxis. Ahora no me deja crearla por la variable log_bin_trust_function_creators. Probe a activarla y me da un error super raro. Dice "FUNCTION CUDATE does not exist". Así que no sé qué hacer. Lo estoy haciendo en una máquina nueva de trabajo. En la que usé siempre MySQL no me daba este error para crear una funcion

Comment: has otra pregunta con ese error y lo miro y avísame cuando la tenga la pregunta

Comment: Gracias Javier.

Comment: de nada @Adrián

Comment: ¡Es `CURDATE` !

Comment: @padaleiana ya se lo solucione https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/528839/error-variable-log-bin-trust-function-creators

Comment: @JavierG.Raya lo vi, pero otras personas puede que no hayan visto la nueva pregunta :)

Comment: Muy cierto @padaleiana por lo que dejo el enlace arriba para que se vea la solución :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** Poner `DELIMITER $$` Antes de borrar la Función en caso de que exista.

***2.*** Es bueno poner un `DROP FUNCTION`  de la función en caso de que exista así podrás modificarlos cuantas veces quieras.

***3.*** Poner el `END $$` y Cambiar el Delimitador a `DELIMITER ;`

***4.*** Tu `SELECT users.username INTO usuario, COUNT(*) INTO veces FROM authentication_tokens.........` Esta mal de debe ser de la siguiente manera `SELECT users.username, COUNT(*) INTO usuario,veces FROM authentication_tokens......`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_maxloginpassbolt() 
CREATE FUNCTION fn_maxloginpassbolt() 
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
     DECLARE usuario VARCHAR(50);
     DECLARE veces numeric;
     DECLARE frase varchar(100);

     SELECT users.username, COUNT(*) INTO usuario,veces 
     FROM authentication_tokens INNER JOIN users
     ON authentication_tokens.user_id=users.id
     WHERE type='login' AND authentication_tokens.created BETWEEN 
     CONCAT (YEAR(CURDATE()),'01-01') AND 
     CONCAT (YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(CURDATE()),'-',DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()),
          ' ',HOUR(NOW()),':',MINUTE(NOW()),':',SECOND(NOW()))
     GROUP BY authentication_tokens.user_id
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
     LIMIT 1;  

     SET frase=CONCAT ('EL usuario que más ha usado Passbolt desde el 1 de enero 
     hasta el dia de hoy durante el año ',YEAR(CUDATE()),'ha sido ',usuario,' con ',
     veces,' inicios de sesion');

     RETURN frase;  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Luego la llamas con `SELECT fn_maxloginpassbolt();` y Solucionado