# ERROR VARIABLE log_bin_trust_function_creators

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando crear la siguiente función:

```
USE passboltdb;

DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_maxloginpassbolt() 
CREATE FUNCTION fn_maxloginpassbolt() 
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
     DECLARE usuario VARCHAR(50);
     DECLARE veces numeric;
     DECLARE frase varchar(100);

     SELECT users.username, COUNT(*) INTO usuario,veces 
     FROM authentication_tokens INNER JOIN users
     ON authentication_tokens.user_id=users.id
     WHERE type='login' AND authentication_tokens.created BETWEEN 
     CONCAT (YEAR(CURDATE()),'01-01') AND 
     CONCAT (YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(CURDATE()),'-',DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()),
          ' ',HOUR(NOW()),':',MINUTE(NOW()),':',SECOND(NOW()))
     GROUP BY authentication_tokens.user_id
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
     LIMIT 1;  

     SET frase=CONCAT ('EL usuario que más ha usado Passbolt desde el 1 de enero 
     hasta el dia de hoy durante el año ',YEAR(CUDATE()),'ha sido ',usuario,' con ',
     veces,' inicios de sesion');

     RETURN frase;  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pero me da siempre este error:

> You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

He probado poniendo esto pero no va:

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

Con esto la función sí me deja crearla, pero al hacer el ***SELECT*** dice esto:

> FUNCTION passboltdb.CUDATE does not exist

Comment: te lo acabo de solucion resulta que hay un **curdate** que tienes mal en el SET porque en lugar de poner ``YEAR(CURDATE())`` pones ``YEAR(CUDATE())`` avisa si funciona @Adrián

Comment: Gracias otra vez. Debí crear esta función muy gafe jjaja

Comment: De nada amigo no me di cuenta de lo que era hasta que leí el error y vi no existe cudate y mire todos tus curdate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1)*** Tu `SET frase=CONCAT ('EL usuario que más ha usado Passbolt desde el 1 de enero hasta el dia de hoy durante el año ',YEAR(CUDATE()),'ha sido ',usuario,' con ', veces,' inicios de sesion');` Esta mal porque en el año pone `YEAR(CUDATE())` y es `YEAR(CURDATE())` Lo solucione de la siguiente manera : `SET frase=CONCAT ('EL usuario que más ha usado Passbolt desde el 1 de enero hasta el dia de hoy durante el año ',YEAR(CURDATE()),'ha sido ',usuario,' con ', veces,' inicios de sesion');`

Solo es ese error el que he visto al escribir mal la función pues te salta el error de que no existe.

```
USE passboltdb;

DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_maxloginpassbolt() 
CREATE FUNCTION fn_maxloginpassbolt() 
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
     DECLARE usuario VARCHAR(50);
     DECLARE veces numeric;
     DECLARE frase varchar(100);

     SELECT users.username, COUNT(*) INTO usuario,veces 
     FROM authentication_tokens INNER JOIN users
     ON authentication_tokens.user_id=users.id
     WHERE type='login' AND authentication_tokens.created BETWEEN 
     CONCAT (YEAR(CURDATE()),'01-01') AND 
     CONCAT (YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(CURDATE()),'-',DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()),
          ' ',HOUR(NOW()),':',MINUTE(NOW()),':',SECOND(NOW()))
     GROUP BY authentication_tokens.user_id
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
     LIMIT 1;  

     SET frase=CONCAT ('EL usuario que más ha usado Passbolt desde el 1 de enero 
     hasta el dia de hoy durante el año ',YEAR(CURDATE()),'ha sido ',usuario,' con ',
     veces,' inicios de sesion');

     RETURN frase;  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No te olvides de votarla positivamente si te sirvió @Adrián

Comment: Creo que ya la voté. No es con el tick verde ?

Comment: es la fecha hacia arriba ^ el tick verde es que te ha funcionado y la solucion a tu pregunta es la del tick